# Gremlin pagination via RangeLocalStep(0,1) fails on an empty traversal

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I've followed the [Gremlin pagination receipe](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#pagination) and find it works fine in all scenarios, except when you ask for 1 item against an empty traversal, then it fails with an error:

***The provided start does not map to a value: []->[NeptuneMemoryTrackerStep, RangeLocalStep(0,1)]***

Asking for one item from a non-empty traversal works fine. Asking for 0 items, 2 items or 10,000 items from an empty traversal is also fine!

Behaviour is as-expected with no errors except when asking for **exactly 1 item from an empty traversal**.

How can I make pagination resilient and work against queries that find no data when consumers are asking for exactly one item?

```
g.inject([])
.as('items','count')
.select('items','count')
.by(range(local, 0, 1))
.by(count(local))
.project('count', 'items')
.by(select('count'))
.by(select('items'))
```

BTW this is running on AWS Neptune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the query just in the Gremlin Console perhaps further illustrates why this happens with values of 2 in the first case and 1 in the second.

```java
gremlin> g.inject([]).
......1>  as('items','count').
......2>  select('items','count').
......3>  by(range(local, 0, 2)).
......4>  by(count(local)).
......5>  project('count', 'items').
......6>  by(select('count')).
......7>  by(select('items')) 
==>[count:0,items:[]]


gremlin> g.inject([]).
......1>  as('items','count').
......2>  select('items','count').
......3>  by(range(local, 0, 1)).
......4>  by(count(local)).
......5>  project('count', 'items').
......6>  by(select('count')).
......7>  by(select('items'))    
The provided start does not map to a value: []->[RangeLocalStep(0,1)]
```

The reason this happens is that any call to `range` with a length greater than 1 will return a list. However, when at most 1 item can be returned a single value gets returned, which in this case is essentially "nothing" and hence there is no value to put into the final `project` result. You will have to change the query to allow for this if an empty result and a range of length 1 is something you expect to encounter.

To further illustrate the difference, see the example below:

```java
gremlin> g.inject([1,2,3]).range(local,0,2)
==>[1,2]

gremlin> g.inject([1,2,3]).range(local,0,1)
==>1
```

Here is one way to adjust your query so that all of these cases still yield a result.

```java
gremlin> g.inject([]).
......1>  as('items','count').
......2>  select('items','count').
......3>  by(coalesce(range(local, 0, 1),constant([]))).
......4>  by(count(local)).
......5>  project('count', 'items').
......6>  by(select('count')).
......7>  by(select('items')) 

==>[count:0,items:[]]
```

Comment: Thankyou Kelvin Lawrence, interesting!!!

I understand from your explanation (re-stated in my own words) that range(0,1) returns a single item or nothing, not a list.

Your coalesce adjustment seems to work perfectly and solves the problem.

Thanks again (and for your amazing Practical Gremlin book, which is brilliant).